# How to avoid show parameters in the browser address bar after RequestDispatcher.forward?

Tags: java, forward, requestdispatcher

I have the following code :

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(viewName);
// while viewName is another servlet name;
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

It's a successful forwording except parameters are shown in the browser address bar. Something like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/testweb/action/LoginAction/login?username=apcpros%40163.com&password=12234
```

I DO NOT want to show any parameters (e.g. **username** and **password**) in the browser address bar after forwording.
What should I do?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: I made a little mistake. I used a GET method in the jsp.

Answer (score 3):

Forward as POST and not GET? That's a GET and if it contains parameters they will need to be forwarded, or remove.

Comment: My class extends HttpServlet. I do forword in the doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) method. In the doGet() method, I just call doPost().

Comment: thanks you a lot. I used a GET method in the jsp page.